# Inductor value given in OHM/Amp

Tags: resistance, inductor, inductance, inductive, reactance

I've been trying to figure out the inductance in Henries from a schematic of a Rabbit Microprocessor development board, however, instead of finding an inductance value over the components in question, theres an ohm/amp value, I thought maybe it was the inductive reactance, but theres only DC in this circuit and most of the inductors are probably being used as filter elements. However , to add more confusion, in this same schematic, some inductors are stated in Henries while others are stated in Ohms/Amps.

***So how should I interpret an inductor whose value is in ohms, It cant be inductive reactance can it? ***

I dont understand how is it related or is it simply a ferrite bead with a certain dc resistance? Here are pictures of the schematic im analyzing:

Here you can see one of the inductors in ohms

[image: Inductor in ohms]

This second pic is also from the same schematic, while there is an inductor stated in Henries (nH to be precise) the other inductor is in ohms

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right in your assumption that those 'inductors' are simply ferrite beads. Some engineer has been lazy and didn't use a distinctive label/reference designator, although the ohms and amps do give it away somewhat.

Ferrite beads are characterized by their DC current rating and characteristic impedance at 100MHz, which is the ohms-value you read there. Their actual DC resistance is much lower, much less than 1 ohm typically.